# How to select parts of text from markdown with regexp?

Tags: regex

I have next text:

```
#Header
my header text

##SubHeader
my sub header text

###Sub3Header
my sub 3 text

#Header2
my header2 text
```

I need to select text from "#Header" to "#Header2".

I tried to wrote regexp: http://regexr.com/3ffva but it's do not match what i needed.

Comment: Does Headers contains `#` in middle of Heading text/name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`^#[^#\n]+([\W\w]*?)^#[^#\n]+`](https://regex101.com/r/pm4weq/1)

Basic idea: find first level-1 heading, find any text *until*... second level-1 heading.

- `^#[^#\n]+` first level-1 heading

  - `^` start of line (because of multi-line flag)
  - `[^#\n]+` Any character that isn't `#` or a newline character. Repeat 1 or more times.
- `([\W\w]*?)` any text until next matching part
- `^#[^#\n]+` second level-1 heading (see above)

Flags: multiline.

Comment: Works with python regex. Just need to take index from match start to group end.

Answer (score 1):

With looking ahead for closing capture and also matching, before next heading:

1- without multi-line flag

```
(^|\n)#([^#]+?)\n([^]+?)(?=\n#[^#]|$)
```

[Demo without multi-line flag](https://regex101.com/r/8e7nPL/3)

Description:

- Group 1 captures first of string or new line that follows # and no other #, that means new Heading starts there.
- Group 2 captures Heading title
- Group 3 captures any thing till the next heading or end of string
- Group 4 is non-capturing and looks ahead for new heading, or end of text.

---

2- with multi-line flag

```
^#([^#]+?)\n([^]+?)(?=^#[^#])
```

[Demo with Multi-line flag](https://regex101.com/r/8e7nPL/2)

Description:

- first, add `#--` at the end of text, for matching last Heading by this regex!
- Starts matching from first char of line by `^` and matches `#` with no # in heading text. Group 1 captured: *Heading* before `\n`
- Group 2 captures texts till next Heading start, that defined by just one # at starting line.

Comment: ECMAScript regex. For python check comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your regex flavor you can use:

`(^#{1}.+)(.*\n)*`

As shown here: http://regexr.com/3fg08

Alternately, you can use Vim's very magic mode:

`\v(^#{1}.+)(.*\n)*(^#{1}\w+)`